# Laravel Authentication with external API

Tags: php, laravel

I have an external server API made with node JS and mongo. I suppose user API is `localhost:8010/api/login` output how do I use that for auth in laravel ?

```
"users": [
  {
    "_id": "592e71bc05be3c26f6bda51d",
    "updatedAt": "2017-05-31T07:33:16.608Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-05-31T07:33:16.608Z",
    "userToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiRW1qb3kiLCJkYXRlIjoxNDk2MjE1OTk2NTk0fQ.25AY8EGoCmpcToidVWBU_czOKCFbV-dkrmCPUx6InD4",
    "name": "desert",
    "mobile": "123456789",
    "type": "N",
    "is_active": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Comment: Post your code, what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Auth::login method will see your desired job

```
$model = User::find(1);
Auth::login($model, true);
```